# How to copy a volume to external volume with a different filesystem?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, cmd.exe

I connected an external hard drive  to my computer. I want to copy the content of the volume D:\ (NTFS) to the connected hard drive which is labeled by F:\ (FAT32). What is the command to copy from D:\ to F:\ ? Won't it be a problem if they do not have the same filesystem ? I know I can use this command: `vol copy start -S D:\ systemA:F:\`  according to the official documentation but I am not sure about the exact syntax (for example what systemA means and if the filesystem difference is not a problem.

Comment: You understand you cannot copy a file larger then 4GB to a FAT32 fileystem right?

Comment: You can't copy the volume (volume is synonymous with filesystem) but you can copy all the files. `xcopy /E /V d:\*.* f:\ ` .

Comment: @FrankThomas thank you very much, your command works !